# Where do I put the IPN url in the sandbox of Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I have an asp.net website that is supposed to allow users to make payments with Paypal.  I want to test it with the Paypal sandbox.

So I created a developer/business account at "developer.paypal.com'.

Using this account  I created a lot of fake email accounts, some personal, some business, for testing.  But now, I want to tell the website to enable IPN, and also, to send IPN notifications to a particular URL.  I don't see a place on the site to do that.  (I assume this would be in the sandbox site, not in the real site).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling it on the account level (log into the sandbox account and set it there). There is an IPN simulator as well.

Comment: I logged in with my developer account, and I see 2 tabs: applications and dashboard.  'applications' takes you to "My Apps", sandbox accounts", and "IPN simulator".  'Dashboard' takes you to 'rest api' 'sandbox notification' and 'create paypal app'.  But none of this tells me where to put a URL of my asp.net page where notifications of paypal transactions will be sent.

Comment: You need to actually open the Sandbox Paypal site and go into the account options for your seller account and set it there. I've found this to be the most effective way to ensure it's set right.